# Wifi to Wifi hotspot Ubuntu studio 22.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, interface

I really want to use only Ubuntu, but one thing stop me for now...
In Windows 10 64 bits, I can create a hotspot Wi-Fi when I am connected to Wi-Fi access point.

Impossible on Ubuntu Studio 22.04 64 bits. I know my interface Wi-Fi intel 3165 AC dual-band can manage it because work on Windows.

I need it because where I am the access point is great, but every client is separated, no local networking is possible.

For example I can see my Chromecast on the laptop but no way to cast. Thats why I need my own Wi-Fi network and with internet sharing!!

**On Windows 10 64 bits: working well Internet is shared and laptop have internet too:**

**my wifi interface:**

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
```

**result of** `ipconfig/all`:

```
Carte réseau sans fil Connexion au réseau local* 1 :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 08-D4-0C-EB-9E-F3
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Oui
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte réseau sans fil Wi-Fi :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 08-D4-0C-EB-9E-F2
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Oui
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::9e93:f16e:2fd:55c8%12(préféré)
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 10.216.224.57(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Bail obtenu. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : lundi 25 décembre 2023 07:19:36
   Bail expirant. . . . . . . . . . . . . : mardi 26 décembre 2023 08:19:36
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 10.216.224.1
   Serveur DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.216.224.1
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 101241868
   DUID de client DHCPv6. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2D-07-40-23-D8-CB-8A-F2-48-5E
   Serveurs DNS. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.216.224.1
   NetBIOS sur Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Activé

Carte réseau sans fil Connexion au réseau local* 10 :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 0A-D4-0C-EB-9E-F2
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Oui
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::c0c7:6da9:8948:c6b%3(préféré)
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.137.1(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 51041292
   DUID de client DHCPv6. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2D-07-40-23-D8-CB-8A-F2-48-5E
   Serveurs DNS. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS sur Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Activé
```

**on Ubuntu working well, but no internet on devices include laptop:**

**result of** `nmcli device show` **on Ubuntu:**

```
nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:D4:0C:EB:9E:F2
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connecté)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     BlåkorsGjest
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.216.224.57/22
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.216.224.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.216.224.0/22, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 10.216.224.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.216.224.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::a4cd:4efd:f23b:b63b/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (inconnu)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (déconnecté)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         D8:CB:8A:F2:48:5E
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (indisponible)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               arrêt
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
```

**and** `nmcli device show` **with hotspot activate:**

```
nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:D4:0C:EB:9E:F2
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connecté)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     jean-hotspot
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.42.0.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.42.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3fd7:357e:81d7:679f/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (inconnu)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (déconnecté)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         D8:CB:8A:F2:48:5E
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (indisponible)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               arrêt
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

**result of** `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 81
       serial: 08:d4:0c:eb:9e:f2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.2.0-1018-lowlatency firmware=29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode ip=10.216.224.57 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:133 memory:df300000-df301fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: d8:cb:8a:f2:48:5e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=6.2.0-1018-lowlatency latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:df200000-df23ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

I hope somebody can resolve my problem, I tried many topics already.
Tried in terminal or with GUI `network-manager`, nothing works. The Wi-Fi driver seams to be the right one also, if needed, just ask for more info.

I have also a ready to use Ubuntu 22.04 running in windows WSL

Ubuntu studio is fast installed on its own partition.

I find also some  solution , it works but the connection rate is soooooo slllloooowwww...

but i share it maybe somebody need.

```
    git clone https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot

#cd in download mape:

    cd linux-wifi-hotspot

#build binaries:

    make

#install:

    sudo make install

#run GUI to configure and start the hotspot with:

    wihotspot

#add "create-ap.conf" in startup

    systemctl enable create_ap
```

I got this when I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1498278/wifi-to-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-studio-22-04/1498289#1498289):

```
sudo bash lnxrouter --ap wlp2s0 TLF-JEAN -p 00000000
linux-router 0.7.1b (https://github.com/garywill/linux-router)
Released under LGPL, with no warranty. Use on your own risk.

PID: 37202
Target interface is wlp2s0 (08:d4:0c:eb:9e:f2)   PCI: 0000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
Use random LAN IPv4 address 192.168.51.1
Creating a virtual WiFi interface... 
x0wlp2s0 created
Channel not specified, use default
Set x0wlp2s0 unmanaged by NetworkManager
Assigning MAC address 08:d4:0c:eb:9e:fc to virtual interface x0wlp2s0 according to wlp2s0 ...
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
Error occured

ERROR: Failed bringing x0wlp2s0 up



Doing cleanup.. 
Undoing iptables changes ..
Exiting: This is the only running instance
Cleaning up done
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`linux-router`](https://github.com/garywill/linux-router) script:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/garywill/linux-router/master/lnxrouter
```

To create an AP, run the following command from the working directory:

```
sudo lnxrouter -i enp3s0
sudo bash lnxrouter --ap wlan0 MyAccessPoint -p MyPassPhrase
```

Comment: thanks i try it right away.

Comment: @JeanBataille see my edit.

Comment: Still not working...